# FadeToogle Jquery dont works the selector next on this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-selectors

Well, i have a div hide in my content and make a buttom to show this but the problem is i have  many elements whit this names so i make this function to solve:

```
$("a.all_com").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll("div:first").slideToggle();
});
```

This function dont works, i try use meet this:

```
$("a.all_com").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle();
});
```

and

```
$("a.all_com").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll("div").slideToggle();
});
```

Nobody works whit me please someone solution, the this is to apply some in the element actually.

My code to show/hide is this:

```
<div id="task_footer">
    <a href="#" id="comment_buttom" class="new_com">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comentar</a>
    <a href="#" id="comment_buttom" class="all_com">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comentários</a>
</div>

<div id="comment_list" style="display:none;" >
    <% tasks.comments.each do |c| %>
        <% if c.user %>
            <p class="one_comment">
            <strong><%= c.user.email %></strong>
            <%= c.comment %>
            </p>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same `id`, `id`s should be unique.

Comment: for each task have a #comment_list, i should make .comment_list ? This will works?

Comment: You should at least change at least one of those `#comment_buttom`s to something else, probably use a class `comment_buttom`. The same is true for all other elements on your page. However, I don't know if this will solve your problem for you.

Comment: No have any sugestion ?